# How to set the parameter dictRemoveWS to true in Apache Ruta

Tags: apache, ruta

`dictRemoveWS` is related to Wordlist. I want to remove whitespace issue in my custom ruta script taking wordlist from txt file.

The documentation says to use `CONFIGURE` method with following example:

`ENGINE utils.HtmlAnnotator;
Document{->CONFIGURE(HtmlAnnotator, "onlyContent" = false)};`

But still I'm unable to set `dictRemoveWS` parameter to true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters like this can be configured on the engine configuration:

In Java:

```
AnalysisEngineFactory.createEngine(RutaEngine.class, typeSystemDescription,
                RutaEngine.PARAM_SCRIPT_PATHS, scriptsPath,
                RutaEngine.PARAM_RESOURCE_PATHS, resourcesPath,
                RutaEngine.PARAM_MAIN_SCRIPT, "Main",
                RutaEngine.PARAM_DICT_REMOVE_WS, true)
```

or in XML definition:

https://github.com/apache/uima-ruta/blob/trunk/example-projects/ExampleProject/descriptor/BasicEngine.xml

See Ruta documentation for more information:
https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.ae.basic